# Can we conclude $n=p-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

Let $\ n\ $ be a positive integer and $\ p\ $ a prime number such that $$\ p^2\mid (2n)! + n! + 1$$ The only pairs $\ (n,p)\ $ I found so far are

$(1,2)$ , $(2,3)$ , $(10,11)$ , $(106,107)$ , $(4930,4931)$

In each pair we have $\ n=p-1\ $.

> Can we prove that this is always the case ? Are there infinite many primes $\ p\ $ such that $$p^2\mid (2p-2)!+(p-1)!+1$$ ?

Comment: See [A079853](https://oeis.org/A079853).  Your list of primes are those for which $(p-2)!\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}$ and, it seems, no more of them are known. (N.B.  it's not obvious, to me anyway, that your primes actually coincide with this list...I'm just matching the sequence).

Comment: @lulu, why is $p^2$ shouldn't it be $p$ by extension of Wilson's theorem?

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I was unclear.  All I did was to match the sequence of primes.  I did not try to prove that the two sequences match.

Comment: @user675453 This would hold for every prime, but what we need here does not.

Comment: @Peter, your question is far beyond my understanding (realised Later). I was just interested in that comment because it seems false

Comment: For every prime $\ p\ $ we have $$p^2\mid (2p-2)!+p$$ hence my divisibility is equivalent to $$p^2\mid (p-1)!+1-p$$ which means $$(p-1)!\equiv (p-1)\mod p^2$$ hence $$(p-2)\equiv 1\mod p^2$$

Comment: But this does not prove that $\ n=p-1\ $ is actually necessary.