# Is there another perfect power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, perfect-powers

This is related to this question : [Can we conclude $n=p-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737644/can-we-conclude-n-p-1)

For which positive integers $\ n\ $ is $$(2n)!+n!+1$$ a perfect power ?

For $\ n=1\ $ and $\ n = 2\ $ , we have a perfect power and there is no more perfect power for $\ n\le 8000\ $

> Can we prove that $$(2n)!+n!+1$$ cannot be a perfect power for integer $\ n>2\ $ ?